# How to get Element Children Attributes with JQuery From Passed in Element

Tags: jquery

I have a function that takes an element as a parameter and from there I need to get attribute info from one of the child elements.

```
function getTablesForSchema(element) {
    alert(element); 
    var schemaName = $(element).children('ul:first').attr('id');    
    alert(schemaName);
...
```

The alert displays [object HTMLLIElement] so I know the element parameter is correct. The 'li' element has a couple embeded 'ul' elements inside of it and I need to get the first one and it's 'id' attribute.

If I do an alert on the element like so the alert fails. I'm at a loss here. Any ideas?

```
var tempElement = $(element);
alert(tempElement);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the alert fails? You're saying it doesn't pop up at all?

Comment: What error is thrown? ... it's kind of important to know that.

Comment: How does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var schemaName = $(element).children('ul:first').attr('id');
```

The above code should work if the 'ul' element is a direct child of 'element'. Otherwise you may want to use this instead:

```
var schemaName = $(element).find('ul:first').attr('id');
```

Comment: They both work. It helps when you have the right path to the jquery.js ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var schemaName = $(element).children('ul:first').get(0).id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JavaScript console in Firefox (with Firebug) or in Chrome? They have `console.log(element)`. A bit better tool too for debugging than alert.